# How to right align numeric data to right in dataTables

Tags: datatables

I am using dataTables plugin. I see that numeric data is not right aligned.

- Is this how dataTables work?
- Have I incorrectly formatted in the data?
- How do I write functionality that checks the data type of each cell of a dataTable and aligns the data to right if it is numeric?

The plugin I used is from here: http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Are you talking about jquery datatables? I've edited the tag but the question is so vague I'm beginning to doubt my decision.

Comment: Please show an example of a table with data (rows). Incorporate the HTML the question.

Comment: Almost all answers below are wrong or dont really answer the question especially regarding third point.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the columns definition you can use className:

```js
$("#tabDatos").dataTable({
  columns: [
    { data: "fecha" },    
    { data: "importe", className: "text-right" }
  ]
});
```

And define the css class "text-right" if you aren't using Bootstrap

Comment: Depending on the version, this might help too: `className: "dt-right"`

Comment: Thanks dear, it worked for me in datatable 1.10.12 version.

Answer (score 7):

I used ColumnDefs to align data:

```
"columnDefs": [{ targets: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], className: 'dt-body-right' },
                           { targets: [0, 1, 2], className: 'dt-body-center' }],
```

- Column Number 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 aligned to the right side
- Column Number 0, 1, 2 is aligned to the center

OR
By directly applying class

```
 { 'data': 'TotalMaleFarmers',className: "text-center" },
```

Answer (score 6):

When you define your datatables object you can optionally customize the column types including adding a css class.  You can then use that class to do anything with that column.

```
$('#myTable').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [

      { "sClass": "numericCol", "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
      //You can also set 'sType' to 'numeric' and use the built in css.           
    ]
  } );
```

The value for aTargets is the index of the column you want to apply this class to.

In your CSS have something along the lines of

```
.numericCol{
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: No what I want is, If a cell has a numeic data it has to right aligned and if it has a string data it has to be left aligned. It should work on entire table. We can do this using external jquery. I wanted to know if there's a clean way to do this in dataTables

Comment: This is a clean way to do it in datatables if you want total control over the appearance. There is another option which I added as a comment where you set the sType property to 'numeric'. However if that does not achieve the total appearance you were after set a custom css class.

Comment: This is much better for rendering (td & text-align): 
td.numericCol{
  text-align: right;
}

Answer (score 3):

here is my solution.

```js
$('#itemTable1').dataTable({bPaginate: false, bFilter: false, bInfo: false, bSort: false});

$('#itemTable2').dataTable({bPaginate: false, bFilter: false, bInfo: false, bSort: false});

$('#itemTable3').dataTable({bPaginate: false, bFilter: false, bInfo: false, bSort: false});

$('#itemTable4').dataTable({bPaginate: false, bFilter: false, bInfo: false, bSort: false});

$('#itemTable5').dataTable({bPaginate: false, bFilter: false, bInfo: false, bSort: false});

//For fourth example
$('#itemTable4 td.numval').css('text-align', 'right');

//For fifth example
var tableData = [['5100','Bacon',1,'KG',400],['5101','Chilly',500,'GM',30],['5102','Pepper',1,'KG',250]];

$.each(tableData, function(i, item) {
  $('#itemTable5').DataTable().row.add([
       tableData[i][0], 
       tableData[i][1], 
       tableData[i][2], 
       tableData[i][3],
       tableData[i][4]
     ]).draw();
});

// after loading data 
$("#itemTable5 tbody tr").each(function() {           $(this).find('td:eq(2)').addClass('numcol');      $(this).find('td:eq(4)').addClass('numcol');
});

$('#itemTable5 td.numcol').css('text-align', 'right');
```

```css
table td.numcol {
  text-align : right;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Example 1 : Using Align Attribute</h2>
    <table id="itemTable1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item Id</th>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Item Qty</th>
          <th>Item Unit</th>
          <th>Item Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>5100</td>
          <td>Bacon</td>
          <td align="right">1</td>
          <td>KG</td>
          <td align="right">400</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>5101</td>
          <td>Chilly</td>
          <td align="right">500</td>
          <td>GM</td>
          <td align="right">30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5102</td>
          <td>Pepper</td>
          <td align="right">1</td>
          <td>KG</td>
          <td align="right">250</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <h2>Example 2 : Using Style </h2>
    <table id="itemTable2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item Id</th>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Item Qty</th>
          <th>Item Unit</th>
          <th>Item Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>5100</td>
          <td>Bacon</td>
          <td style="text-align:right;">1</td>
          <td>KG</td>
          <td style="text-align:right;">400</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>5101</td>
          <td>Chilly</td>
          <td style="text-align:right;">500</td>
          <td>GM</td>
          <td style="text-align:right;">30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5102</td>
          <td>Pepper</td>
          <td style="text-align:right;">1</td>
          <td>KG</td>
          <td style="text-align:right;">250</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <h2>Example 3 : Using Class </h2>
    <table id="itemTable3">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item Id</th>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Item Qty</th>
          <th>Item Unit</th>
          <th>Item Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>5100</td>
          <td>Bacon</td>
          <td class="numcol">1</td>
          <td>KG</td>
          <td class="numcol">400</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>5101</td>
          <td>Chilly</td>
          <td class="numcol">500</td>
          <td>GM</td>
          <td class="numcol">30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5102</td>
          <td>Pepper</td>
          <td class="numcol">1</td>
          <td>KG</td>
          <td class="numcol">250</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <h2>Example 4 : Using JQuery for static table</h2>
    <table id="itemTable4">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item Id</th>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Item Qty</th>
          <th>Item Unit</th>
          <th>Item Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>5100</td>
          <td>Bacon</td>
          <td class="numval">1</td>
          <td>KG</td>
          <td class="numval">400</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>5101</td>
          <td>Chilly</td>
          <td class="numval">500</td>
          <td>GM</td>
          <td class="numval">30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5102</td>
          <td>Pepper</td>
          <td class="numval">1</td>
          <td>KG</td>
          <td class="numval">250</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <h2>Example 5 : Using JQuery for dynamic table</h2>
    <table id="itemTable5">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item Id</th>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Item Qty</th>
          <th>Item Unit</th>
          <th>Item Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
    
  </body>  
</html>
```

i hope u find something useful from above code... cheers...

Answer (score 2):

In version 1.10.19 to align my 2nd and 3rd column right, I do this:

```
$('#myDataTableHere').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: [1, 2], className: "right-aligned-cell" },
    ]
}
```

Obviously, my CSS has a class `.right-aligned-cell` with `text-align: right;` to actually get the result.

Note:
HTML-documentation suggests, that using CSS class `.dt-body-right` you would be able to do the same. That does not work for AJAX-approach.

Comment: May I ask what the discrepancy is? This solution works for me and few other people?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution that work with version 1.10.16 with any column:

```
$.fn.table = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    self.DataTable({
      columnDefs: self.find('th').map(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        return {
          render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
            if (data === (+data).toString()) {
              return '<div style="text-align: right">' + data + '</div>';
            } else {
              return data;
            }
          },
          targets: self.index()
        };
      }).get()
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Else one variant for firts column
to align to the right or some type of edition to the style, so you can use css style in your page

```css
style{
 #myTable td:nth-child(1){text-align: right;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 4,   // target column
            "className": "text-right",
            "width": "15%"
        }]
```

Create style:

```
.text-right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's been a few hours now, I've been racking my brains to get the numbers aligned to the right in "print" mode. Someone knows how to get the alignment to the right of the numbers when printing.

The html I have it well formatted, but when printing everything goes to the left.

You can use some function that when detecting a type of label such as "" everything that is inside it can be assigned an alignment. This way we could put numbers inside that label and align them to the right.

Thank you very much for the help you can give me.

Answer (score -1):

It seems from your comments you are talking about actually printing the table data via a printer. If so you need to make a **print stylesheet** and/or set the **@media query to print** within your custom css stylesheet.

**I prefer to do both**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/assets/print.css">

@media print{

img{display:none;}
.text-right{float: right; clear:none;}
etc...

}
```

As per the data table's class identification it is very simple.

```
$("#table1").dataTable({
  columns: [
    { data: "account name"}
    { data: "balance", className: "text-right" }
  ]
});
```